# Can we write react-native applications without any knowledge of Android or Swift?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, react-native, mobile-application

I am planning to write mobile apps for multi platforms and heard about react native as a good tool.

With little study, my understanding is that it's just for UI and you will end up using Android/IOS for part of your app coding.

Is it possible to write entire app in react native without Android knowledge?

My app needs to interact with other apps on the device like youtube, cal, WhatsApp, mail.. etc

Comment: why do you think it is me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes it is possible to write an entire app for both platforms Android and IOS, without Android knowledge, and without Swift Knowledge.

However, when some react native code works fine on IOSs but not on Androids, then you will have to do some *bridging* and have to write in Java for Android (requires Android Knowledge). Notice the `android` folder in your project? That is where Android-Specific code would be written.

And visa versa for things that work on Android but not on IOS, you will have to write in Swift and expose your code. Notice the `ios` folder?

Comment: I understand and noticed those folders. But my question is what if I need to invoke other apps from my app like invoking Facebook or WhatsApp from my app to share some content? Even for those do we have react-native components that will work for both iOS and Android?

Comment: @reddy I am not sure about your specs but you can look them up and make sure that there are stuff out therr for your need. I assume yes it is possible and components exist for _sharing stuff on Whatsapp and Facebook_

Comment: Agree. Very new to UX and ReactNative. I noticed react-native component is available for the same. https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share